# ahk script to access "Outlook Data Files"

Tags: script, autohotkey

what would be the autohotkey script for MS Outlook that will enable to access directly to the "Outlook Data File" view of the Contacts Folder?

```
+!c::  ;it does not work for "Outlook Data File" View but it does work for a customized View
```

ComObjCreate("Outlook.Application").ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder := ComObjCreate("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(10) ;Contacs opens
ComObjActive("Outlook.Application").ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Views.Item("Outlook Data File").Apply ;Apply "Outlook Data File" view
         Return

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok I added my script, that it does work with views that I created but it does not work for "Outlook Data Files"